# If every locally constant function on a metric space X is constant, is X a connected metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

[image]

The other direction was quite easy, but this direction is giving me some difficulties. One idea I had was to show that I can form a chain of non-disjoint open ball from one element to another which would prove X is connected, but I'm not sure how to get there.

Comment: Use an indirect proof: assume that X is not connected and try to constract a non-constant locally constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y_1,y_2 \in Y$, $y_1 \neq y_2$. If $X=U \cup V$ where $U$ and $V$ are non-empty disjoint open sets then $f(x)=y_1$ for $x \in U$, $f(x)=y_2$ for $x \in V$ defines a non-constant locally constant function  $:X \to Y$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a non-empty subset of $X$ such that $X\setminus A$ is also open. Then the map$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&X&\longrightarrow&Y\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}y_1&\text{ if }x\in A\\y_2&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}\end{array}$$is locally constant. Therefore, it is constant, and so $B=\emptyset$. This proves that $X$ is connected.